# Changing the color of the .setTextColor when the checkbox is using setEnable(true)

Tags: android, checkbox

There are some problem that I cannot solve by myself.
I'm currently making a simple android app  for my training that utilizes multiple checkbox's.

What I want to do is as the title says, change the color of the text of the checkbox when the the condition is setEnabled(true).
I've searched through google but couldn't find the solution to it. I've added the sample code that I'm using below. Sonce, I'm a noob the help from the pro's means a lot to me.

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {

                        buttonView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);


                        buttonClicked.add(buttonView.getText()
                                .toString());
                        buttonView.setTextSize(18);
                        count += 1;
                        Log.d("TAG","is checked = "+isChecked);
                        if (count >= 7) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {

                                String item = Integer.toString(i+1);
                                if (buttonClicked.indexOf(item)>-1) {
                                    checkbox[i].setEnabled(true);

                                    Log.d("TAG",i+" = 2is checked = "+isChecked);
                                //  buttonView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                } else {

                                    Log.d("TAG",i+" = 3is checked = "+isChecked);
                                    checkbox[i].setEnabled(false);
                                //  buttonView.setTextColor(Color.RED);


                                }


                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        if (count <= 7) {

                            for (int i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
                                checkbox[i].setEnabled(true);
                            //  buttonView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


                            }
                        }
                        count--;


                        buttonClicked.remove(buttonView.getText()
                                .toString());
                        buttonView.setTextSize(15);

                    }
```

Comment: are you searching for `setChecked(boolean value)`? Your question is not clear, Can you make it more clear, it will be very helpful for us to help you :)

Comment: Sorry for my poor dialog. The problem is  that I cannot set the color of the text of the checkbox efficiently. For example,  if I press more than 7 checkbox's, all  of the checkboxes will have the black text color, however,in the current code I'm using, when I uncheck  the checkbox,　instead of the black color, the green color sets up. I find this difficult.  In other words, I want to make all the colors of the text black when unchecked  and also  checkbox of the checked checkbox when unchecked. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the selector xml and put that in 
**/res/color/text_my_checked.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#00ff00"/> 
<item android:color="#000000"/> <!-- anything else -->
</selector>
```

And use that in layout file like this

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check"
    android:textColor="@color/text_my_checked"
    android:checked="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the textcolor of check box as follows ,

```
yourCheckBox.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one option:

```
checkboxbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            Checkbox b = (CheckBox)v;
            if (b.isChecked()) {
                  //your code
                  b.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

            }
            else 
                 //your code
                 b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

          }
        });
```

Also, you can choose color defined in color.xml file

```
b.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```